# correlation with time

Tags: time-series, correlation, pearson-r

I have data that represents starting time and duration, and I need to know if they are correlated. I thought to convert time to `int`, considering only the hour, and use Pearson correlation.

I don't know if it really makes sense to use Pearson correlation with time. It sounds like checking the trend of a time series.  Do you think this can be correct?

I also wonder: Is the time supposed to be a categorical datum, in which case Pearson is not really the best way to quantify the correlation?

Answer (score 1):

If starting time is expressed as [Unix time](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time), then you could use seconds since the Unix epoch 00:00:00 UTC on 1 January 1970 for both the start time $S_{epoch}$ and end time (start time plus the duration) $E_{epoch}$. So we would end up having two variables of Unix seconds.  $RankCorr(S_{epoch}, E_{epoch})$ can be computed, [ranked correlation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rank_correlation). Plain Pearson can also be computed and compared.

However, since time is a relative term, this could be a multivariate problem too i.e., both start and end timestamps could generate more variables such as day, month or similar. Then we would have a similarity issue between two sets of features.